# Nginx - Reverse proxy - add request header to each request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-headers

I have nginx as a reverse proxy. I am trying to add a request header for each request, so i tried:

```
location / {
 proxy_pass some.host.com;
 proxy_set_header MY_HEADER somename;
}
```

But the header is not added to the request (At least i don't see it in the F12 debugger tool -  Request Headers or in Postman).

I have a client, and i want to display there an iframe of dashboard from another app. i need to send to that app request header with my username to pass the autentication. so i thought about a reverse proxy where the iframe point to the reverse proxy and the proxy add the request header and.

Any ideas how can i attach the request header to each reqeust?

Comment: You already added the request header!

Comment: @MichaelHampton i know, but it doesn't add it, i don't see it in the developer tools in Request Headers.

Comment: Why would you see it there? That's in your browser!

Comment: @MichaelHampton i am making the request to a client. there is a client that requires a header for authentication, so i pass every request through the reverse proxy and add the header there. and then i should be able to put iframes from the site in my app

Comment: OK, but that still won't show up in your browser.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so how would i know if the header is added? also why do i see some other request headers  there like host and more...

Comment: You had nginx add the header. That is far beyond your browser. If you want to know whether it was added, you'll have to check the application that you passed it to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but if i add response header (with add_header) i see it in the browser, i dont understand why i can't see the request header?

Comment: You can't see the request header in the browser because it was never there! This is pretty obvious stuff.

Comment: @MichaelHampton why is it not there then? that's what im saying in the question, i don't understand why it isn't there?

Comment: You didn't add the request header in your browser, you added it on the server! It is a request header. It would never be sent back, because it's not a response header.

Comment: i understand now, so do you have any idea how should i approach this? i need the header for authentication

Comment: You have said very little about what you're actually doing, so I couldn't begin to guess. I would suggest you start over from the beginning and explain your real problem.

Comment: I have a client, and i want to display there an iframe  of dashboard from another app called spotfire. now there is a way to pass the authentication in the app if i add an header with the specified username  (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-0E4154FC-97AE-43D4-8EBF-A9BD9380D83C.html).
so i thought i would make the src of the iframe point to the reverse proxy and there it will add the header and pass the request to spotfire and i would pass the authentication. but as you said i can't add there request headers in the reverse proxy.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the last comment was too long to at you. also, as they say in the link i sent: Header: Enter the name of the HTTP request header that contains the name of the authenticated user

Comment: Please add relevant details to the question itself, not as a comment. Also, Michael never said that you cannot add request headers in the reverse proxy. You can add the request headers there, but you only see the added request headers in your application. They are never visible to your browser.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen so did i send the request headers right? beacuse i didn't pass the authentication of the website with the header, so if guessed it didn't work. btw does that mean that if the website i'm sending the request to isn't mine there is no way for me to know if the request headers are there? also i edited the question

Comment: Yes, the directive adds headers to the proxied request. And yes, the headers are only visible in the request from the reverse proxy server to the final destination. If you can inspect the request on the proxy server, then you can see the real outgoing headers. How to actually inspect it is a separate topic.

Comment: how can i inspect it?
and another question, do you know if redirect (301/302) removes the request headers?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen forgot to add you in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

That IS adding the header but since it’s happening server side you won’t see it in your browser (client side). If you want to ensure that the header is being added to your proxied request a quick way to check:

have netcat listen on some ephemeral port on your server where nginx is
`nc -lvp 40200`

once listening modify your `nginx.conf` to point to the listening netcat instance
`proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:40200;`

restart nginx
`systemctl restart nginx`

then go to the nginx endpoint in your browser you’ll see the full HTTP request on stdout